# Setting Body to 100% height with NuxtJs

Tags: nuxt.js

Am working on a project with Nuxtjs codebase, writing an admin panel. I need to make height of my `<body>` 100% as all other element ultimately inherits from it when I set their height to 100%. I have tried to find settings to do so I could not.

Any idea is appreciated

Answer (score 2):

Please use the code below to acheive what you asked for.

```
html,body, #__nuxt, #__layout{
  height:100%!important;
  width: 100%!important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for the answer to this and as I read your question it dawned on me. Add it to the css for the layout file in your /layout directory